# Overwriting files vs deleting them?

Tags: memory, bsod, memory-management, overwrite

(I hope this is the right community to ask)

Throughout the day, I need to save various images to my computer and then dispose of them soon after. Because of this, I created a PNG file called TempImage on my computer that I can just overwrite each time I need a new file for a short period of time. I thought this would be better than saving a new file with a new name each time. Is it? Or is more of my RAM being wasted by overwriting the files? I just got this new computer and I received a PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA error from, what I've looked up online, means memory issues. I got this error twice in a row right after accepting a call in Skype, which I know can use a lot of memory, so it kind of makes sense. Should I be worried about my memory? I've overwritten it approximately 286 times. Should I stop doing this and make a new file each time? What can I do to fix my computer? Is it as simple as running a Memory Diagnostic tool? Or do I need to get it repaired? This computer came with Windows 10.

**Diagnostic Results**

The WDT didn't find any errors. Neither did the chkdsk command.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.

Any other ideas why it would happen? I don't think the computer is even a month old yet... I have only downloaded 3 programs on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to agree with MrStatic

I would also recommend this source for potential fixes: http://www.technicalnotes.org/how-to-fix-page-fault-in-nonpaged-area-best-fixes/

Unnecessary Elaboration: (to help answer your concerns about wearing out the memory):
When you save a picture (or any file for that matter) it is written to your hard drive not to your ram (what is generally referred to as memory).  Of course it will be stored in ram (and in paged memory) while you are editing/viewing it but ram (DRAM) has a very high MTBF and will likely take MANY years to fail (think 1000 years) as unlike flash it uses capacitors and, as I understand it, does not degrade with use.  It is FAR more likely that you have a faulty ram stick, given how new it is, than that you did something to cause it.  Your ram is constantly re-written regardless of what you do, this is normal and nothing to worry about.

Replacing a file does not actually mean writing it to the same place.  Rather the reference to that file is replaced with a reference to the new one and the old one is dereferenced (deleted).  The original file will likely remain on your hard drive until it is eventually overwritten.  This is actually better for your hard drive than actually using the same area as it helps your drive to wear evenly rather than wearing out one spot (far more important with SSDs than with magnetic drives).  Many times (as I learned it in school) hard drives use a FIFO queue for available space which means that the last thing you deleted will generally be the last thing overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed elaboration. Just to be clear, are you saying it doesn't matter if I create a new file each time? Or are you recommending to create a new file each time?

Comment: It does not matter.  Both are equal as far as your drive are concerned.  You cannot determine where a file is saved (your operating system does this using various algorithms) and naming it to the same thing every time does not affect how it is saved.  Unless you are using a flash based Solid State Drive you will probobly never have to worry about your drive failing.  SSDs try to even the wear out evenly  by saving to different locations every time so that failure takes a long time but again this is the operating system / hard drive programmers job and you have little control over this.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your process with the PNG file would have no cause for the Page Fault IN Nonpaged Area. If that process works for you then continue it. It won't cause stress on your system either way.

Generally the reason for getting Page Fault In NonPaged Area is as you saw, issue with memory. This can be caused tho from either or both your hard disk and ram. If you only rarely see this area, it is usually a faulty stick of ram. Run Windows Memory Diagnostic for awhile and see if it indicates an error. If it does, you can't repair it. You will have to replace it.

Also try opening up a command prompt by clicking Start, then type in `cmd`. In the dos style box type in `chkdsk`. If it returns with an error, run the same command again but with a `/F` after it. That can try to repair or move your data around so you can avoid the damaged areas of the disk.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response. The diagonstics Tool is about 50% done, I'll update the post once it finishes (on mobile currently). After that I will try the chkdsk command.

Comment: It seems it is not a faulty stick of RAM since both results came back clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that the hardware is OK, [a page fault is simply a bug](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Invalid_conditions) in the software that throws this fault. It is pretty common in software and is a sign of bad quality, if the software does it often.

I usually think the other way around. First, I assume that the software crashed and *then* if I think that the software has good quality, I get the idea to check the hardware.

Comment: Unless the software came damaged, I didn't drop it or anything. Can I run a hardware test of sorts? I've accepted multiple calls from Skype before and had no problem, why would it be occurring now?

Comment: @MrAwesome8 It's a bug in Windows itself.